# Я так потому говорю, что, если ты этого не сделаешь, возможно(,) будет плохо

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Я так потому говорю, что, если ты этого не сделаешь, возможно(,) будет плохо.

Comment: Лео, у вас личная драма? Был серьезный разговор, да?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я так потому говорю, что **если** ты этого не сделаешь, **возможно**, будет плохо.*

Если это двойной союз на основе **вводного слова**, то запятая не нужна.

**Сравнить:**

*Я так потому говорю, что **если** ты этого не сделаешь, **значит,** просто не можешь сделать.*

Comment: Не подумал-с. Тогда плюс вашему.

Comment: Спасибо, Максим!  Вы мне определенно нравитесь...

Comment: Но ведь можно сказать вполне *Я так говорю потому, что, возможно, будет плохо, если ты этого не сделаешь*.

Comment: Если переставить слово, то мы получим другую структуру предложения. И там другие правила.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, т. к. используется двойной союз ЕСЛИ..., ВОЗМОЖНО:

*Я так потому говорю, что, если ты этого не сделаешь, возможно, будет плохо*.